# Functional testing multilanguage Symfony2 app

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I trying to test my multilanguage app. I have four languages form in my application. I try to test indexAction(), when crawler go through my page I want to check count of title, but title can be in english or in japanese for example. When I pass translation key it does not work. Here is code:

```
$this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('html:contains("logo_text")')->count());
```

So the question is, can I pass translation key into tests? Or I need somehow hardcode value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this solution by Florian Eckerstorfer:
https://florian.ec/articles/use-translation-keys-in-symfony2-functional-tests/

It basically creates a new translator that will return a key instead of a real translation.

```
class NoTranslator implements TranslatorInterface
{
  public function trans($id, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
  {
    return $id;
  }
...
}
```

And than registering it:

```
# app/config/config_test.yml
parameters:
    translator.class: Acme\DemoBundle\Translation\Translator\NoTranslator
```

The blog post also describes possibility of using [Compiler Passes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html). A lot more complex solution so you can start with the one above.

Comment: hm, but why travic-ci didnt see my error, and my friend who help me to create this project etting all tests passed.

Comment: It is hard to answer this question since we don't know how your CI environment is configured. But I would start with investigating if you local tests are working first.

Comment: Not valid for Symfony3 anymore. You will need to use service decoration to replace the translator. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470596/replacing-the-translator-service-in-symfony-3